# Flask - Check if blueprint exists

Tags: python, flask

I wrote my own auth module for a flask application. It isn't ready yet, and can be a pain while I work on other modules. I commented out the line of code where I register the blueprint:

```
# app.register_blueprint(auth_module)
```

but how to I check to see if this module exists in another controller:

`/mod_home/controllers.py`:

```
@mod_home.route('', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    # if mod_auth:  <-- THIS LINE???
        # check if user is logged in, redirect if needed
    # else:
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: Well, I found the answer... not sure if I should close the question or answer it?

Answer (score 1):

```
from src import app
...
auth_mod_used = 'auth' in app.blueprints.keys()
```

This assumes the dir structure of:

```
/project
  /src
    * __init.py__
```

And the `__init.py__` file contains:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```